# Sort DirectReports in rest api sharepoint 2013

Tags: 2013, sharepoint-online, sharepoint-server, rest

Below is the query to fetch the Direct Reports for a particular user . How can is sort by display name in rest api? Can you please help me . I tried like this but it is not working.

```
http://mytest.bullshit.com/_api/SP.UserProfiles.PeopleManager/GetPropertiesFor(accountName=@v)?@v='Bullshit\skondapa'&$select=DirectReports,DisplayName,Title.
```

For **Order By display name** i tried like this

```
**http://mytest.bullshit.com/_api/SP.UserProfiles.PeopleManager/GetPropertiesFor(accountName=@v)?@v='Bullshit\skondapa'&$select=DirectReports,DisplayName,Title,*&$orderby=DisplayName.**
```

Answer (score 1):

It seem the order of retrieved properties specified via `$select` query option is ignored when property of type `Collection(String)` (e.g. `DirectReports`) is specified.

In that case you could consider to **filter** the returned results as demonstrated below:

```
var requestUrl = _spPageContextInfo.webServerRelativeUrl + "/_api/SP.UserProfiles.PeopleManager/GetPropertiesFor(accountName=@v)?@v='" + encodeURIComponent(accountName) + "'&$select=DirectReports,DisplayName,Title";
$.getJSON(requestUrl,function(data){
    var properties = ['DirectReports','DisplayName','Title'];
    var values = [];
    properties.forEach(function(p){
        if(data.hasOwnProperty(p))
           values.push(data[p]);
    }); 
    console.log(values);   
});
```